# Update/Change defaultCalendarForNewEvents of EventStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ekevent, ekeventstore

As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507062-defaultcalendarfornewevents?language=objc) , it is a readonly property but I want to update it dynamically.I have tried to change this property by key/value but no success , though no error occurred but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update it dynamically

I assume you mean: I want to use my app code to set this value.

The documentation implies that this cannot be done, but as with many areas of iOS/macOS, it does not describe the user experience.

The user needs to use the "Default Calendar" setting, you can provide instructions via "helper text", but you cannot change this value (even with the basic calendar-store level permission).

Also, note: in macOS (circa Ventura), the setting is in Calendar.app, and also, if they select a calendar that is not-writable, the menu will let you, but when you read the value, it will use the last valid selection. (User's cannot set the default calendar to "U.S. Holidays" and save to it.)